Would an identical copy of me have the same thoughts as me?
Scenario:
You are placed within a sensory deprivation tank.
Unbeknownst to you, a perfectly identical copy of your current self has been placed in an identical tank, there are no differences in experiences nor memories (t0). 
If you were to then be thinking of how tasty bananas (t0+1) are would your copy be thinking the same thing?
This is ignoring any science behind the feasibility of creating an identical copy.
We are also assuming that at t0 you and the copy have identical positions of all internal components such as cells, atoms etc.
(Apologies if I have used the incorrect tags, I think this may not fit under brain in a vat but it was the closest I could find)

What can “perfectly identical copy” mean? After all, as you climb into your tank, likely a few of your skin cells will rub off, and as your hypothetical twin climbs into “their” tank, maybe a few atoms rub off of that tank’s rim and adhere to your twin. Then—presto!—you two are no longer perfectly identical. And your macro properties are extremely sensitive to initial conditions.  Such sensitivity would require your identicalness down to every microbe on or in you, and to the condition of every such microbe. Even if it were attained for an instant, it couldn’t possibly endure.

Identical at time 0 (while already in the tank). They do not exit during the timeframe of the thought experiment. From that point they would arguably cease being identical (which i personally agree with) however their environment is still the same and any surface changes such as skin cells have no bearing on brain processes and whether or not they would maintain similar thought. The question is more focused on whether or not their thoughts would be the same rather than if they’d technically remain identical for long after t0

Yes, they would have the same thoughts, except that there may be some randomness introduced from quantum effects, which could be amplified over time from chaotic interactions. But I don't think the mind is really that chaotic, so the two minds would have essentially the same thoughts for quite a while.

No. They would think that you are the copy.

Would an identical copy of me wear the same shirt as me?

This question should have been moved to Worldbuilding SE because it is about a fantasy setting.

We do not know, and that is because we have not cracked either the hard or easy problems of consciousness.
What we DO know, is that it is likely that the thoughts would be very similar for the two "yous", but that they are likely to increasingly diverge.
We know the "similarity" will be true because we tend to hold the same thought through multiple changes in our neural activation patterns in our brains.  The continual changes in synapse formation and die-off, and the oscillation of activation wave patterns at the macro level, show that we have continual macro and micro-level self-induced changes, but our thinking is pretty stable anyway.
So the same should be true of the new "you".
However, both the synapse formation/die-off, and the oscillatory waves, strongly suggest the brain is chaotic, and if so, then the "identical you" would NOT be "identical" for more than a moment.  We know what chaotic systems look like, and living things in general are bounded chaotic systems.  The neural net of a brain is as clear a candidate to be a chaotic system as we have ever found in our universe, so one should not expect any brain to be deterministic.
Also, of course, the physicalist assumption that "self == brain" is disputed, and opening up the question to different assumed ontologies will leave the answer even more open-ended.

The answer is a NO. And that's because you cannot occupy the exact same position in space with the original. Since you do not occupy the exact same position, the intarractions (with the environment) have some differences. Whether you want to identify these differentiations as quantum, or physical or whatever is irrelevant. The fact is that from t0 and on, the copy and the original start to have a different life of their own. In the beginning the differences may be minimum, but in the progress of time the two personalities will become quite apart. Since the thoughts reflect both inner states and the interraction with the environment, they are too subject to the same process of differentiation.

+1 What an incredible answer, I was just about to type this.

Due to the famous no-cloning theorem, it is impossible to create an identical copy of you.

+1 ... Perfect!

Externalists about mental content will insist on a negative answer.
You think to yourself: I want to get out of this tank. And your clone thinks to himself: I want to get out of this tank.
You are thinking different thoughts because you are thinking about two numerically different objects. Whether the clone gets out of its tank is not what would satisfy your wish. The thoughts have different truth conditions.
The typical response to this is to accept the conclusion as such, i.e. that the two thoughts are different in the wider sense of being sensitive to differences in reference, but to insist that the thoughts are the same in some narrower sense that is sensitive only to your "psychological state". And to thus assume that we can make good sense of the claim that the two psychological states are the same in this narrow sense.
By itself the distinction between wide and narrow content is an unmotivated terminological suggestion, but even when further developed the idea of narrow content has problems, and externalism is the more widely accepted position in philosophy today.
The internalist will protest that surely we must accept that the cloned brain being an identically organized information processing system must be having the same thoughts. But the main point of externalism is precisely to argue that thoughts, and in fact minds, are not in the head. So appealing to similarities in the brain merely rephrases the internalist position and thus begs the question against the externalist. The right externalist position is probably to insist that we should stop asking incoherent questions like "Where is the mind located?".
Now it's open for the externalist to claim that ultimately with time as the embodied clone is able to interact with itself and the environment it can have same thoughts as you, but this has nothing to do with being an exact replica. Can the embodied clone with its seemingly appropriate dispositions be said to have thoughts about its direct environment immediately upon creation? I wonder (see the discussion around Davidson's Swampman thought experiment).

The question is so hypothetical that only guesses can be given but my guess is no. Even if you have the exact same DNA and circumstances your conscious would not be the exact same. Identical twins start off with identical DNA but there are slight mutations as they get older. Of more relevance identical twins with (starting off) identical DNA and identical upbringing frequently have very different, personalities,  talents and  food preferences. Therefore it is safe to say that while identical DNA and environment do  create an identical external look, it does not create an identical internal thought process. Even a cloned version of someone held in identical circumstances  would still start to mutate slightly and develop it's own conscience

It is very hypothetical but it was part of a debate I was having with a friend and neither of us really had the understanding of the brain/quantum randomness to properly come to a conclusion. The differences emerging in identical twins are generally considered due to slightly different environments or epigenetics, neither have an opportunity to be relevant in this. Over time I agree the consciousness would diverge but it still seems like a completely identical copy initially would still have the same thoughts as the original if given no stimulus to change what they're thinking.

Most people are ignoring that you want to assume you can create a perfect clone. Assuming it's possible to create a perfect clone of you then the answer to that is dependent on if we live in a deterministic universe. The only way we could correctly assert if the clone will act completely like you is if we live in a deterministic universe. Otherwise, we wouldn't be able to guarantee with 100% confidence that the clone will act one way or another.
If we don't live in a deterministic universe then we both don't currently have enough data to make a prediction and, even if we did have enough data, any prediction will not provide 100% certainty

You need to be clear about the concepts.
A copy is not the original, it always differs at some level, and that's your problem.
A "perfect copy", as you say, is factually not possible. From the moment something is not the original, it will always differ at some level. A copy of yours will not have the same atoms, so, quantic phenomena will allow an emergence of a different individual.
Physically, a "perfect copy" in a different position, is impossible. An atom is what it is because of its spatiotemporal qualia (see @Anixx's answer).
Now, if you want to imagine a world that doesn't follow the laws of nature, you enter in a logical inconsistency, which is not interesting, at least in philosophy. In such context, you can accept that web pages grow on trees and that the String Theory describes pasta. And that your clone thinks and acts exactly like you, so, when you go through a door, he smashes his head against a wall.

An individual is not just a function of atoms and cells, life experiences and conditioning play a major role in shaping a personality. If we clone a person then to be deeply identical in thoughts and behaviour there should be a mechanism to pass the same experiences and conditionings. We dont know about any such mechanism unless you look at it from spiritual point of view. Therefore scientifically it is not possible for clones to have same thinking pattern let alone same thoughts.

The results of life experiences and conditioning are in your brain and stored/expressed by neurones there. Because of that I would assume that an identical copy including all brain structures would therefore also have/express the same conditioning and life experiences by the same mechanism it as it would have identical memories. If everything is in the exact same place at t0 including the chemicals/ions that stimulate thoughts then could the same thinking pattern not be maintained?

@MaxPenston Because an individual is just a function of atoms and cells in the body. There is a dimension of consciousness. Unless this clone is cooked in the consciousness it is impossible to maintain same thinking pattern.
